# Unity Panel not showing in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, unity, shortcut-keys, panel

when I log in to my account, it only shows the wallpaper and one folder I have on the desktop. I found some answers where they tell me to open a terminal and reset unity settings, the problem is that I can't open a terminal via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> works but this type of terminal I am not familiar with the control.

Can you please help me.

The guestuser account is working normal, and I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl + Alt + F1 gives you the CLI version of your OS. 
Enter your username when it says `login:` and you will be prompted for password. 
Proceed to type the commands as you do in a normal terminal and things should be fine. 
 
You can switch back to graphical mode by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F7/F8

Here is a [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) to one of the answers to your problem